# Want to show 2 database tables in one view MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ABC()
    {
        var model = new Test.Models.Tables();

        string ABC = "ABC";

        model.TableA = db.TablesA.Where(d => d.ColumnA.Contains(ABC)).ToList();

        model.TableB = (from d in db.TablesA.ToList()
                              join j in db.TablesB.ToList() on d.TableAID equals j.ID
                              select new TableB() { TableBDisplay = j.TableBDisplay });

        List<Tables> allTables = new List<Tables>();
        allTables.Add(model);
        return View(allTables);
    }
```

Model:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
public class Tables: DbContext
{
    public IEnumerable<TableB> TableB { get; set; }
    public List<TableA> TableA { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Test.TableA> TablesA { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Test.TableB> TablesB { get; set; }

}

}
```

View:

I have tried:

```
@model IEnumerable <Test.Models.Tables>

@model List<Test.Models.Tables>

@model IEnumerable<Test.TableB>
```

and a few others. None of these work as far as displaying multiple tables. How can I get this function to work?

Comment: The model you're returning is `allTables` which of type `List<Tables>`, use: `@model List<Tables>` and put a breakpoint to verify it indeed has the correct values in it.

Comment: List<Test.Models.Tables> is what it automatically renames to, otherwise it can't find it.